# Dynamically generating CSS classes at runtime in Angular 7

Tags: css, angular

I have an Angular 7 application where I need to dynamically generate CSS classes in my component at runtime.

First off: I know about `[ngStyle]` and `[ngClass]`! I need to do some stuff using pseudo-selectors which I can't generate using these.

Now, the naive approach: I'll just use Angular to template my CSS!

```
<style *ngFor="let class of classes">
    .{{class.prefix}}-target {
        border: 1px solid maroon;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .{{class.prefix}}-control:hover ~ .{{class.prefix}}-target {
          background: red;
        }
  </style>
```

The problems with this approach:

1. VS Code complains that I'm putting Angular templating inside a CSS class.
2. Angular doesn't interpolate `{{class.prefix}}` in the final resulting HTML- it just literally puts  `{{class.prefix}}` there.

Is there a way to do this in Angular, either with a library that's meant for this or an approach I can use? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how dynamic you need the component to be...

You could declare the prefix (or dynamically generate it) outside of the component class. Then use a JavaScript template string to interpret the styles before they get processed by the @Component() decorator's metadata.

Like so:

```
const classPrefix = 'bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  template: `
    <!-- Your HTML template -->
  `,
  styles: [`
    .${classPrefix}-target {
        border: 1px solid maroon;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .${classPrefix}-control:hover ~ ${classPrefix}-target {
        background: red;
    }
`]
})
export class FooComponent {
/* . . . */
}
```

Comment: how about if we want the background in .${classPrefix}-target class to be dynamic? for example background: somevariable;

Comment: @William Depends on how dynamic they need to be. If they need to be dynamic when the component is composed, the method above would work, just using another variable. If they need to continue being dynamic after the initial render, CSS custom properties might be worth a shot, sometimes called CSS variables. i.e. `background: var(--my-color)`

Comment: @William CSS Custom Properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties